# Are DBT Python models with Snowflake but without Snowpark possible?

Tags: python, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, dbt

A significant chunk of one of my pipelines utilises DBT Python models that write to Snowflake. Originally these were workbooks in Databricks. We have moved everything to Snowflake recently. The code originally generated asynchronous inserts to the DB in a loop. However, Snowpark Session library is not threadsafe, so these inserts are now synchronous. Is there a way to build DBT Python models which will operate "outside" of Snowpark, so that I can use Snowflake Python Connector for async DB calls and not be forced to use Snowpark Session library?

The original Databricks code looked like the following, but Snowpark Session library is not threadsafe

```
pool = ThreadPool(5)
            pool.map(
                lambda statement: execute_statement(statement), statements_list)
```

Comment: What are you looping over? A more detailed question including code examples will help folks answer you

Comment: The snowflake code is just a for loop generating insert statements. Nothing to see really

Comment: The dbt python models in Snowflake work within the Snowpark framework would be the answer to the direct question. But instead of stopping there, I'd like to solve the underlying problem. If you can describe that scenario better and desired results, we'll do our best to work out a solution.